# How do I obtain static property value through mono debug wire?

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, mono

I am trying to control Unity Editor over [Mono Debugger Wire Protocol](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/docs/soft-debugger-wire-format/). I want to obtain value of `public static` [property](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/0cf7cdad8092152ba078b4e306b4182608de040d/Editor/Mono/SceneHierarchyWindow.cs#L16).
The following is my attempt:

```cs
using VirtualMachine = Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine;

// vm points to the virtual machine of the Unity Editor
internal void SomeWhat(VirtualMachine vm) {
    var hierarchyWindow = vm.GetTypes("UnityEditor.SceneHierarchyWindow", false)!.Single()!;
    var prev = hierarchyWindow.GetMethod("SelectPrevious")!;
    var latestWindow = hierarchyWindow
        .GetProperty("lastInteractedHierarchyWindow")
        .GetGetMethod(false)
        .Evaluate(null, new Value[] { });
    
    prev.Evaluate(latestWindow, new Value[] {});
}
```

However, it throws `System.NotSupportedException`:

```
Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at Mono.Debugger.Soft.ILInterpreter.Evaluate(Value this_val, Value[] args) in $PROJECT/deps/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/ILInterpreter.cs:line 43
   at Mono.Debugger.Soft.MethodMirror.Evaluate(Value this_val, Value[] args) in $PROJECT/deps/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/MethodMirror.cs:line 466
   at Blah.SomeWhat(VirtualMachine vm) in $PROJECT/$PROJECT_NAME/SandBox/Lib.cs:line $LINE
```

where `$PROJECT`, `$PROJECT_NAME`, and `$LINE` are variable.

I am confused because of its poor message, and a static [field in Java's reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-) do not require valid `this_val` object. It turns out that `this_val` cannot be null at present.

I am using Unity Editor 2019.4.31f1 and mono/debugger-libs on https://github.com/mono/debugger-libs/tree/6fcc6d78446b1fffac12f597099cc3d78dd74ca6, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[line 42 in `ILInterpreter`](https://github.com/mono/debugger-libs/blob/84c5c67f3eb96749012491088d7970a57459e805/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/ILInterpreter.cs#L42) does check for

> ```
> if (method.IsStatic || ... || this_val == null || ...) 
>    throw new NotSupportedException ();
> ```

so it looks like this - or at least this way - is not made for statics at all.

---

Since in this specific case the property is actually just pointing to a static field

> private static SceneHierarchyWindow s_LastInteractedHierarchy;

you could try to rather go through e.g.

```
var fieldInfoMirror = hierarchyWindow.GetField("s_LastInteractedHierarchy");
var latestWindow = hierarchyWindow.GetValue(fieldInfoMirror);
```

---

Alternatively you could probably also try and go through

```
var property = hierarchyWindow.GetProperty("lastInteractedHierarchyWindow");
var getterMethod = property.GetGetMethod();
var latestWindow = hierarchyWindow.InvokeMethod(null, getterMethod, new Value[0]);
```

---

It depends a lot on your actual use case and purpose of what you are trying to implement.

Usually in a case like yours where you already know exactly what type and members and signatures you are dealing with you would rather use `InvokeMethod` instead of `Evaluate`. The latter as to my understanding you would use more if you do not know the types, members and signatures beforehand.